# C# json array to List

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I want to populate a drop down list with a list of servers I have in a json file.  So I want to retrieve the list from json and use that list to add all of the servers to my drop down.  I have a simple json file with a simple array in it.  In an ideal world, all I want to do is something like this:

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
public static void Main(string[] args = null)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

    Configuration = builder.Build();
    List<string> servers = Configuration["servers"];

    foreach (string server in servers)
        {
            cboSelectServer.Items.Add(server);
        }
}
```

And my `appsettings.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "servers": ["server1", "server2"]
}
```

The message I get is

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to System.Collections.Generic.List<string>

What is really confusing me is that it obviously understands `Configuration["servers"]` is a list because if I look at `Configuration["servers:0"]` I get my first server.

Comment: try this ....  Configuration["servers"].Split(',').ToList()

Comment: Thanks @PraneshJanarthanan, but ToList() isn't an option when I add .Split(',')

Comment: Your appsettings.json contains list of string arrays,  so you set value based on that.   dummy code representation:  List[0] => array.Split(',').ToList()

Comment: @SkinnyPete63 `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of the `GetChildren` call from a `ConfigurationSection` as returned by `GetSection`:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

Configuration = builder.Build();
List<string> servers = Configuration.GetSection("servers")
                                    .GetChildren()
                                    .Select(x => x.Value)
                                    .ToList()

foreach (string server in servers)
    {
        cboSelectServer.Items.Add(server);
    }
```

You'll need a couple of `using`'s at the top of your file:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I am no programmer, just a hack trying to get by, so please bear with me.  I have added the class in, no problem, but when I add the method IOptions gets underlined and there is no quick action to tell me how to resolve it.  Also, is that a method of the class, or just an additional method in Main?  Finally, services (as in services.Configure etc) also gets underlined with no quick action.

Comment: @SkinnyPete63 is this in an MVC/WebApi project? And if so, are you trying to consume this config data in a controller?

Comment: No, it's just a console application.

Comment: Ah right - this is the  wrong answer then. Looking again .

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much for your assistance.